# how to the delete access database in c# programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

We can create a database but why can't we delete it?

I can create an access database using them and perform operations with queries on it.

```
string dbName;
            dbName = textBox7.Text;
            ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "" + dbName + ".accdb;");
            MessageBox.Show("Database created");
            label9.Text += textBox7.Text;
```

I couldn't find any documentation on this topic. I only have this.
can you please help?

Comment: The `.accdb` file *is* the database. Delete the file.

Comment: I thought the same way, but can't we delete it using the drop database statement?

Comment: No. There's no server that contains it like there is in SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, and so on. Once you drop a database in those servers, there's a larger context that you can remain connected to. In Access (and SQLite, incidentally), the file is the database, so dropping it would leave the connection in an invalid state.

Comment: ...therefore, you have to "drop" the database from outside of a connected context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void btnDropDb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dbadin;
        dbadin = textBox7.Text + ".accdb";
        string path = Application.StartupPath;
        path = path + "\\" + dbadin + "";
        File.Delete(@path);
        MessageBox.Show("Database  " + dbadi + " deleted");
     }
```